# How to make resources directory and global message variables work in java or java-ee and adopting it for different languages

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, struts2, internationalization

I saw in a tutorial that I can make a directory called resources in the root path of the project and make a file in the directory called ApplicationResources.properties to define all the messages as a constant to prevent hard coded message insertion in the programmes, I have added the following lines to the file and I tried to use them in the MyClass-validation.xml of my struts2 web project but they weren't replaced with the assigned message.

My file is resources/ApplicationResources.properties:

```
errors.invalid=${getText(fieldName)} is invalid.
errors.required=${getText(fieldName)} is required.
errors.number=${getText(fieldName)} must be a number.
errors.range=${getText(fieldName)} is not in the range ${min} and ${max}.
```

1. If this method is correct, how can I insert them in the java programmes? or I only can use them for configuration files?
2. If this method isn't correct what should I have done?
3. How can I use it for i18n?
4. Should the variables min, max come from the message variable scope? In the configuration file they should come from the tags attributes.

XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
    <validators>
        <field name="duration">
            <field-validator type="int">
                <param name="min">1</param>
                <param name="max">1000</param>
                <message key="errors.range"/>
            </field-validator>
        </field>
    </validators>
```

The tutorial is [Create Struts 2 Application in Eclipse](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-struts-2-application-eclipse-example/). BTW, my project structure is the eclipse default structure: MyProject/(src resources WebRoot)

Comment: There is some xml code in the question that is not displayed. I couldn't solve the problem. Instead of the code it displays 1 1000

Comment: Numbered list was causing it, added "XML:" and indented a bit further.

Comment: Thanks for finding and solving the problem.

Comment: Please note that this tutorial targets a very old version of Struts 2.

Comment: so you mean that the resources bundle doesn't work any more and I should take another approach for organizing the messages?